# SD cards and Linux Live storage

Tags: linux, partitioning, sd-card

Here's my scenario... I've got several USB thumbdrives with various Linux distros running on them, pretty much all of them with persistence, although only about 4GB per distro. I have a 32GB micro-sd card unused and was wondering if I can segment it with gparted, using whichever formatting would work best, and use this one SD card as extended storage for multiple Linux OSes?

Perhaps EXT4 for Ubuntu/Kubuntu/Studio, Kali, and Fedora....and ReiserFS for Knoppix...Either a large EXT3 or 4 partition that can be used by multiple distros, or several partitions used by one distro each?

Just thought I'd see if I can get some feedback before I spend a few hours doing it! LoL

Comment: What exactly are you asking? You can do all of the above, *i.e.* break up the card into multiple partitions, or keep a single large partition to be used by all distros. But what are you trying to achieve? What are your aims?

Comment: Bear in mind that to actually share the same files, you will need to look at the user IDs on the different distros.  Different distros don't necessarily use the same default user ID.